# How to save correct format of price in DB using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

When I type in the textbox `price` and then submit the form a value of

```
25100
```

it is saved in the DB as `25100.000`

But when I type a price like `25.100` it is saved as is.

My price type in mySQL is `decimal(10,3)`

My question is how can I type `25100` and have it saved as `25.100` ?

Comment: You can't. Perhaps you're confusing the continental system of expressing currency with that employed in the modern world.

Comment: You'd be better off just storing everything as cents and doing the conversion on output only... it will avoid rounding errors.

Comment: What @GaryHayes said. Don't confuse the **internal representation** of the price (which is important for comparing and otherwise doing accounting, and needs to avoid rounding errors) with the **display** of that price.

Comment: Just to confirm, how much is 25100.000 in words? Is it "twenty-five thousand one hundred" or "twenty-five million one-hundred thousand"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FORMAT`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-format-function.php) . which works for floating point numbers as well as for integers

Try this:

```
    SELECT FORMAT(your_column_number, 3) from your_table;// -->  25,100.000
    SELECT FORMAT(your_column_number, 0) from your_table;// -->  25,100
```

or if you wanna insert it then use this

```
    INSERT into table (id , column_number) Values (1 , FORMAT(25100, 3))
```

EDIT>

```
    INSERT INTO used (price) VALUES (FORMAT('$price', 3))
```

Comment: Thank you but how I can do this using PHP? I am insert like `INSERT INTO used (price) VALUES ('$price')`